# Where can I download the newest boot repair disk?

Tags: downloads, disk

I have a boot repair disk for Ubuntu 12.04 and I'm about to install Ubuntu 14.04 but I'd like to make sure that I have the latest boot repair disk before doing so.  Where can I download the most recent boot repair disk?

Comment: There is no "Recovery Disk". Please clarify what you mean.

Comment: You can get a better answer if you provide more info, like if you mention whether you have separate root and home partitions or not, if you intend to do an upgrade or a fresh install, etc...

Comment: This install will all go on one partition and be a completely fresh install.  I meant a Boot Repair Disk, sorry.  Where can I download the latest Boor Repair Disk?

Comment: What do you intend to do with the boot repair disk? In my experience I have never used a boot repair disk, when using ubuntu. I have used a live cd, with a program called boot-repair on it, but never a boot-repair/recovery disk. What is that you want to happen? If you intend to do a backup, then grab an external hard drive and backup the files that you want saved. IMO Backing up files and doing a fresh install is the best 'boot-repair'.

Comment: @jmunsch - Convert that into an answer - something along the lines of boot 14.04 from a live usb and install boot-repair. add a link to the boot-repair page. FWIW - boot-repair is a useful tool to help if someone is having problems with grub, but, IMO, many times the problem is with uefi and not grub, so additional information is required when people have boot problems. IMO boot-repair is advised too often without understanding the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The boot-repair-disk can be downloaded from the sourceforge.net website at this link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/?source=recommended

Most recent computers need the 64-bit version of the boot-repair-disk. For repairing 32-bit Linux operating systems with boot-repair-disk you need the 32-bit one.

The RSS feed that has update notifications about the latest version of boot-repair-disk is at this link: http://sourceforge.net/api/file/index/project-id/578971/mtime/desc/limit/20/rss